# I want all the records till the end of the file which are greater than given date in unix

Tags: unix

I want all the records till the end of the log file which are greater than given date... 
suppose given date is   Mon Dec 14 22:00:03 2015  then i want all the lines in the log file till end when first occurrence of greater than this date is found.

ex:  awk ' { if  ( $0 > "Tue Dec 15 08:00:00 2015") print } ' file.out

- only prints lines greater than date but i want all lines after match till end of file..

please note that 
1. i can not use regex since i dont know if entry is present in the log file for that date i.e H:M:S  so i have to use greater than date functionality.

2. Date is not present on every line of the lg file. it is present in between but on new line

please help

sample log file:::

```
Mon Dec 14 02:00:00 2015
Clearing Resource Manager plan via parameter
Mon Dec 14 07:02:57 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12504, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)(CID=(PROGRAM=oracle)(HOST=ltest8)(USER=oracle)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.115)(PORT=1521)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
    TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
  Time: 14-DEC-2015 07:02:57
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564

TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Dec 14 08:01:37 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12504, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)(CID=(PROGRAM=oracle)(HOST=ltest8)(USER=oracle)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.115)(PORT=1521)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
    TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
  Time: 14-DEC-2015 08:01:37
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564

TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Dec 14 08:54:33 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12504, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)(CID=(PROGRAM=oracle)(HOST=ltest8)(USER=oracle)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.115)(PORT=1521)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
    TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
  Time: 14-DEC-2015 08:54:33
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564

TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Dec 14 08:57:18 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 232
  Current log# 2 seq# 232 mem# 0: /u04/app/oracle/oradata/kcom/redo02.log
Mon Dec 14 08:57:19 2015
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/kcom/Rialto/trace/Rialto_arc3_3953.trc:
ORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 268435456 bytes is 100.00% used, and has 0 remaining bytes available.
************************************************************************
You have following choices to free up space from flash recovery area:
1. Consider changing RMAN RETENTION POLICY. If you are using Data Guard,
   then consider changing RMAN ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY.
2. Back up files to tertiary device such as tape using RMAN
   BACKUP RECOVERY AREA command.
3. Add disk space and increase db_recovery_file_dest_size parameter to
   reflect the new space.
4. Delete unnecessary files using RMAN DELETE command. If an operating
   system command was used to delete files, then use RMAN CROSSCHECK and
   DELETE EXPIRED commands.
************************************************************************
Mon Dec 14 09:17:45 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12504, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)(CID=(PROGRAM=oracle)(HOST=ltest8)(USER=oracle)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.115)(PORT=1521)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
    TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
  Time: 14-DEC-2015 09:17:45
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564

TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Dec 14 10:25:24 2015
QKSRC: ViewText[ecode=942] = SELECT /*+ result_cache */ ID, 'PLUGIN_'||NAME AS NAME, STANDARD_ATTRIBUTES, SQL_MIN_COLUMN_COUNT, NVL(SQL_MAX_COLUMN_COUNT, 999) AS SQL_MAX_COLUMN_COUNT, SQL_EXAMPLES FROM WWV_FLOW_PLUGINS WHERE FLOW_ID = :B2 AND PLUGIN_TYPE = :B1 
Mon Dec 14 14:31:14 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 233
  Current log# 3 seq# 233 mem# 0: /u04/app/oracle/oradata/kcom/redo03.log
Mon Dec 14 14:31:15 2015
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/kcom/Rialto/trace/Rialto_arc0_3947.trc:
ORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 268435456 bytes is 100.00% used, and has 0 remaining bytes available.
************************************************************************
You have following choices to free up space from flash recovery area:
1. Consider changing RMAN RETENTION POLICY. If you are using Data Guard,
   then consider changing RMAN ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY.
2. Back up files to tertiary device such as tape using RMAN
   BACKUP RECOVERY AREA command.
3. Add disk space and increase db_recovery_file_dest_size parameter to
   reflect the new space.
4. Delete unnecessary files using RMAN DELETE command. If an operating
   system command was used to delete files, then use RMAN CROSSCHECK and
   DELETE EXPIRED commands.
************************************************************************
Mon Dec 14 20:28:23 2015
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 234
  Current log# 4 seq# 234 mem# 0: /u04/app/oracle/oradata/kcom/redo04.log
Mon Dec 14 20:28:24 2015
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/kcom/Rialto/trace/Rialto_arc1_3949.trc:
ORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 268435456 bytes is 100.00% used, and has 0 remaining bytes available.
************************************************************************
You have following choices to free up space from flash recovery area:
1. Consider changing RMAN RETENTION POLICY. If you are using Data Guard,
   then consider changing RMAN ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY.
2. Back up files to tertiary device such as tape using RMAN
   BACKUP RECOVERY AREA command.
3. Add disk space and increase db_recovery_file_dest_size parameter to
   reflect the new space.
4. Delete unnecessary files using RMAN DELETE command. If an operating
   system command was used to delete files, then use RMAN CROSSCHECK and
   DELETE EXPIRED commands.
************************************************************************
Mon Dec 14 22:00:00 2015
Setting Resource Manager plan SCHEDULER[0x2C09]:DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via scheduler window
Setting Resource Manager plan DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via parameter
Mon Dec 14 22:00:03 2015
Mon Dec 14 22:00:03 2015
Logminer Bld: Lockdown Complete.  DB_TXN_SCN is   UnwindToSCN (LockdownSCN) is 18957974
Tue Dec 15 02:00:00 2015
Clearing Resource Manager plan via parameter
Tue Dec 15 02:00:02 2015
```

Comment: are you bound to any specific languages or tools?

Comment: want to run it on unix system so anything would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simple python 2 parser with hardcoded datetime and input file. Tested with your given log. It has plenty of room for optimization but it works as a start I guess.

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import re
from datetime import datetime

# year, month, day, hour, minute
filter_from = datetime(2015, 12, 13, 23, 40)

with open("tmp.log") as log:
    match = False
    for line in log:
        if (match):
            print line
        else:
            candidate = re.match(r'[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [A-Z][a-z][a-z] \d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d\d\d\d', line)
            if candidate:
                parsed_date = datetime.strptime(candidate.group(0), "%a %b %d %X %Y")
                if parsed_date > filter_from:
                     match = True
                     print line
```